# Bash loop never ends

Tags: bash

I wonder why this script never ends?

```
#! /bin/bash
for ip in `seq 200 254`; do
ping -c 1 192.168.0.$ip | grep "bytes from" | cut -d " " -f 4 | cut -d ":" -f 1 &
done
```

But if I choose not to run commands in parallel, script ends up just ok.

```
#! /bin/bash
for ip in `seq 1 254`; do
ping -c 1 192.168.0.$ip | grep "bytes from" | cut -d " " -f 4 | cut -d ":" -f 1 
done
```

Could somebody explain, please, why is it happens?

Comment: You put it into the background. It's not running in parallel.

Comment: Are you sure it is never ending?   Putting:  & just runs it in the background.  Are you sure it is being passed and sitting up in the processeS?

Comment: what happens if you wrap the seq in `$()`, like the following:   `for ip in $("seq 200 254"); do`

Comment: FYI, `seq` is not a standard command, and not all systems supporting bash ship it.

Comment: @Fallenreaper, backticks and `$()` are completely equivalent except when nesting (except for readability purposes). OTOH, by adding quotes on the _inside_, you're looking for a command with a name like `"/usr/bin/seq 200 254"`, and that's not likely to exist. (If you added them on the outside, you'd iterate only once, with a single value of `ip` that looks like `200 201 202 ...`).

Comment: The better practice is a C-style for loop: `for (( i=200; i<254; i++ )); do ...; done`.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. Like David C. Rankin have said below, I just can't see termination of the script, but it runs correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loops are doing the exact same thing. The only difference is that in the first instance you are running all commands in the background and will not see a termination. Specifically:

```
ping -c 1 192.168.0.$ip | grep "bytes from" | cut -d " " -f 4 | cut -d ":" -f 1 &
                                                                                ^^^
```

Using the `&` operator at the end tells bash to background the process. Eliminating the `&` runs the process in the foreground where the execution is visible.